# Replacing the return value - from DataPortal to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

```
 public static CustomizeCourseCompletionWithModuleList GetCustomizeCourseCompletionWithModuleList()
{
    var cmd = new StoredProcedure
    {
        CommandText = "CustomizeCourseCompletionWithModuleSelectById",
        CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DBNull.Value);
    return DataPortal.Fetch<CustomizeCourseCompletionWithModuleList>(cmd);
}
```

***In the end instead of returning DataPortal I want to return DataTable, how should I do this ?***

CustomizeCourseCompletionWwithModuleList class :

```
public class CustomizeCourseCompletionWithModuleList : BusinessListBase<CustomizeCourseCompletionWithModule>
{
    #region  Business Methods

    public CustomizeCourseCompletionWithModule GetItem(int childId)
    {
        return this.FirstOrDefault(child => child.Id == childId);
    }

    public override void Remove(int childId)
    {
        foreach (var child in this.Where(child => child.Id == childId))
        {
            RemoveChild(child);
            break;
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(int childId)
    {
        return this.Any(child => child.Id == childId);
    }

    public bool ContainsDeleted(int childId)
    {
        return DeletedList.Any(child => child.Id == childId && child.IsDeleted);
    }

    #endregion
```

StoredProcedure :

```
public class StoredProcedure : ICloneable
{
    private Parameters _parameters = new Parameters();
    private string _procName;

    public StoredProcedure(string name)
    {
        _procName = name;
        CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    }

    public StoredProcedure()
    {
        CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public String CommandText
    {
        get { return _procName; }
        set { _procName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public System.Data.CommandType CommandType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _procName; }
        set { _procName = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public Parameters Parameters
    {
        get { return _parameters; }
        set { _parameters = value; }
    }


    #region ICloneable Members

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return GetClone();
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    protected virtual object GetClone()
    {
        return ObjectCloner.Clone(this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

If u need any other information please ask, so you can give me a proper answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is returning a `CustomizeCourseCompletionWithModuleList`  What are you actually looking to do?

Comment: By returning DataPortal, it goes through 60 files so I can get the whole information, since services are not needed, because it can be done local, I need to remove service related DataPortal and to make it return my business object or datatable so I can sort it and operate with it easily. Also I will need it because of the pagination, I dont have need to load all of the pages when the report is called, but only those records which are on the selected page. I hope I explained my idea enough considering my English bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful but I did some digging and I came across this article that talks about using [CLSA's ObjectAdapter](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=770361&seqNum=4) in order to transform a list into a DataSet. Csla.Data.ObjectAdapter

```
//Get the a musicians BusinessBaseList
MusiciansList musicians = MusiciansList.GetList();

//Use the ObjectAdapter to transform the list into
//a DataSet
ObjectAdapter adapter = new ObjectAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, musicians);

//Bind the DataSet to the musician’s 
//DropDownList
ddMusicians.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
ddMusicians.DataTextField = "LastName";
ddMusicians.DataValueField = "Id";
ddMusicians.DataBind();
```